# Plot a line chart with conditional colors depending on values

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a line chart. Depending on values it should change its color.
What I found is:

```
plot(sin(seq(from=1, to=10,by=0.1)),type="p", 
       col=ifelse(sin(seq(from=1, to=10,by=0.1))>0.5,"red","yellow"))
```

That works. But as soon as I change from type="p" to type="l" the conditional colouring disappears.

Is that behavior intended?

What is a solution with base graphics to plot a functional line with different colors?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `segments` instead of `lines`.

The `segments` function will only add to an existing plot.  To create a blank plot with the correct axes and limits, first use `plot` with `type="n"` to draw "nothing".

```
x0 <- seq(1, 10, 0.1)
colour <- ifelse(sin(seq(from=1, to=10,by=0.1))>0.5,"red","blue")

plot(x0, sin(x0), type="n")
segments(x0=x0, y0=sin(x0), x1=x0+0.1, y1=sin(x0+0.1), col=colour)
```

See `?segments` for more detail.

[image]

Comment: When you add `abline(h = 0.5)` you will note that the colors do not change at the indended value.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a little different approach:

```
x <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=0.1)
plot(x,sin(x), col='red', type='l')
clip(1,10,-1,.5)
lines(x,sin(x), col='yellow', type='l')
```

[image]

Note that with this method the curve changes colors at exactly 0.5.

Comment: Cool, a less general approach yet it yields more accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

After you've drawn a line plot, you can color it with `segments()`:

```
seq1 <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=0.1)
values <- sin(seq1)
s <- seq(length(seq1)-1)
segments(seq1[s], values[s], seq1[s+1], values[s+1], col=ifelse(values > 0.5, "red", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that without drawing a line first you'll have to set up all the plot limits and axis yourself, which is tedious. Or maybe I haven't found a way.

Comment: When you add `abline(h = 0.5)` you will note that the colors do not change at the indended value.