# xyplot time series with positive values in green, negative in red, in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Is there a neat way to color negative values in red and others in green for a (simplified) time series plot below, using `lattice::xyplot`?

```
set.seed(0)
xyplot(zoo(cumsum(rnorm(100))), grid=T)
```

[image]

Comment: If histogram is ok then: `xyplot(z, type = "h", col = ifelse(z > 0, "green", "red"))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lattice is based on `grid` so you can use grid's clipping functionality

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)

set.seed(0)
x <- zoo(cumsum(rnorm(100)))

xyplot(x, grid=TRUE, panel = function(x, y, ...){
       panel.xyplot(x, y, col="red", ...) 
       grid.clip(y=unit(0,"native"),just=c("bottom"))
       panel.xyplot(x, y, col="green", ...) })
```

[image: lattice with clipping]

Answer (score 4):

When using type="l" you only have one "line" and it's all one color, so you might instead choose to color points:

```
set.seed(0); require(zoo); require(lattice)
vals <- zoo(cumsum(rnorm(100)))
png()
xyplot(vals, type=c("l","p"), col=c("red", "green")[1+( vals>0)], grid=T)
dev.off()
```

[image]

I found a solution by, [Sundar Dorai-Rag,  a fellow now at Google,](http://research.google.com/pubs/author38116.html) to a similar request (to color the enclosed areas above and below 0, for which his approach to  getting the crossing values for the X's was to invert the results of `approx` ) as seen here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/shading-under-the-lines-in-a-lattice-xyplot-td793875.html. Instead of coloring the enclosed areas, I gave the borders of the polygons the desired colors and left the interior "transparent":

```
lpolygon <- function (x, y = NULL, border = NULL, col = NULL, ...) { 
   require(grid, TRUE) 
   xy <- xy.coords(x, y) 
   x <- xy$x 
   y <- xy$y 
   gp <- list(...) 
   if (!is.null(border)) gp$col <- border 
   if (!is.null(col)) gp$fill <- col 
   gp <- do.call("gpar", gp) 
   grid.polygon(x, y, gp = gp, default.units = "native") 
} 

find.zero <- function(x, y) { 
   n <- length(y) 
   yy <- c(0, y) 
   wy <- which(yy[-1] * yy[-n - 1] < 0) 
   if(!length(wy)) return(NULL) 
   xout <- sapply(wy, function(i) { 
     n <- length(x) 
     ii <- c(i - 1, i) 
     approx(y[ii], x[ii], 0)$y 
   }) 
   xout 
} 

trellis.par.set(theme = col.whitebg()) 
png();
xyplot(vals, panel = function(x,y, ...) { 
        x.zero <- find.zero(x, y) 
        y.zero <- y > 0 
        yy <- c(y[y.zero], rep(0, length(x.zero))) 
        xx <- c(x[y.zero], x.zero) 
        ord <- order(xx) 
        xx <- xx[ord] 
        xx <- c(xx[1], xx, xx[length(xx)]) 
        yy <- c(0, yy[ord], 0) 
        lpolygon(xx, yy, col="transparent", border = "green") 
        yy <- c(y[!y.zero], rep(0, length(x.zero))) 
        xx <- c(x[!y.zero], x.zero) 
        ord <- order(xx) 
        xx <- xx[ord] 
        xx <- c(xx[1], xx, xx[length(xx)]) 
        yy <- c(0, yy[ord], 0) 
        lpolygon(xx, yy, col = "transparent", border = "red") 
        panel.abline(h = 0) ;panel.grid(v=-1, h=-1 )
     }); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean about "one line" (between adjacent positive and negative values). I was hoping that there is a way to show this line in two colors, green above zero and red below zero. This may involve adding points to the graph (to break lines crossing zero ordinate), possibly with linear interpolation. Hopefully, there is an automated function or a parameter to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I tried writing a custom panel function for this that will break a line on a given value

```
panel.breakline <- function(x,y,breakat=0,col.line,upper.col="red",lower.col="green",...){
    f <- approxfun(x,y)
    ff <- function(x) f(x)-breakat
    psign <- sign(y-breakat)
    breaks <- which(diff(psign) != 0)
    interp <- sapply(breaks, function(i) uniroot(ff,c(x[i], x[i+1]))$root)
    starts <- c(1,breaks+1)
    ends <- c(breaks, length(x))

    Map(function(start,end,left,right) {
        x <- x[start:end]
        y <- y[start:end]
        col <- ifelse(y[1]>breakat,upper.col,lower.col)
        panel.xyplot(c(left, x, right) ,c(breakat,y,breakat), col.line=col,...)
    }, starts, ends, c(NA,interp), c(interp,NA))
}
```

You can run with

```
library(zoo)
library(lattice)
set.seed(0)
zz<-zoo(cumsum(rnorm(100)))

xyplot(zz, grid=T, panel.groups=panel.breakline)
```

[image]

And you can change the break point or the colors as well

```
xyplot(zz, grid=T, panel.groups=panel.breakline, 
    breakat=2, upper.col="blue", lower.col="orange")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If one was to do it without points, then I'd stick to plot (instead of lattice) and use clip , like in one of the answers here : 
[Plot a line chart with conditional colors depending on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344018/plot-a-line-chart-with-conditional-colors-depending-on-values)

```
dat<- zoo(cumsum(rnorm(100)))

plot(dat, col="red")

clip(0,length(dat),0,max(dat) )
lines(dat, col="green")
```

Comment: Thanks. I must use xyplot for consistency. Surely there is a similar neat approach :)

Comment: `plotrix::color.scale.line` is also a nice option.