# multiarea chart in lattice

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lattice, stacked-area-chart

I am pushing `lattice` to its limits.

Consider this example

```
tibble(time = c(ymd('2019-01-01'),
                      ymd('2019-01-02'),
                      ymd('2019-01-03'),
                      ymd('2019-01-01'),
                      ymd('2019-01-02'),
                      ymd('2019-01-03'),
                      ymd('2019-01-01'),
                      ymd('2019-01-02'),
                      ymd('2019-01-03')),
             variable = c('a','a','a','b','b','b', 'c','c','c'),
             value = c(1,2,3,0,0,2,2,4,3)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_area()
```

[image]

Using the nice solution in [how to create a stacked area chart in lattice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570680/how-to-create-a-stacked-area-chart-in-lattice) does not work here, perhaps because we have multiple areas.

Can we still do it with `lattice`?
Thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579576/how-to-change-the-fill-color-in-a-lattice-plot for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

df1 <- tibble(time = c(ymd('2019-01-01'),
                       ymd('2019-01-02'),
                       ymd('2019-01-03'),
                       ymd('2019-01-01'),
                       ymd('2019-01-02'),
                       ymd('2019-01-03'),
                       ymd('2019-01-01'),
                       ymd('2019-01-02'),
                       ymd('2019-01-03')),
              variable = c('a','a','a','b','b','b', 'c','c','c'),
              value = c(1,2,3,0,0,2,2,4,3))

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(val=cumsum(value))

xyplot(val~time, df2, group=variable,
       panel=function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyarea(x,y,...)
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)},
       alpha=c(0.9,0.6,0.3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: nice! but are you able to set the colors using the `par.settings` trick? it does not work for me

Comment: thanks bro. pretty useful. ggplot is pretty useless for time series

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ you can use `par.settings=simpleTheme(col=c("red", "blue","green")),
       alpha=c(1,0.3,0.1)` not perfect tho. And you kidding about `ggplot` and `timeseries` right?

Comment: yeah... the problem is that you cant really choose the colors because they are overlayed... on my real chart this is super messy... maybe there is an alternative solution here?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ what's your beef with `ggplot`? that would do the job. If you want to have `a` at the bottom and `c` at top, just refactor the data.

Comment: thanks bro. just kidding about ggplot. but lattice is great for dual axis and quick ts viz

Comment: maybe some additional subtleness. do you know how to add a legend/key that maps to the colors?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ maybe this would work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805016/xyplot-time-series-with-positive-values-in-green-negative-in-red-in-r

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Last comment. I am crazy, but you can try to make couple shp files with the points for each of those areas and plot those shape files and then add an axis and make the labels to show what you actually need. All I can think of. Again, that's crazy. It's much easier to fool ggplot and secondary axis with different scale than doing what I just said.