# Plot line in different colors above versus below zero

Tags: r, plot, colors

I'd like the plotted line to be blue for values above zero and red for values below zero.

Sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(1:10, c(-2, -3, -1, 1, 2, 1, -2, 2, 4, 3))
plot(dat, type = "l", lwd = 2)
abline(h = 0, col = "grey")
```

Result:

[image: image of resulting plot]

Expected result:

[image: image of expected resulting plot]

I do not want to use ggplot2 and would prefer a solution in base R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a line chart with conditional colors depending on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344018/plot-a-line-chart-with-conditional-colors-depending-on-values)

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350635/11117265) [as @Sonny suggested in the comment], you can do this using `clip`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(u = 1:10,
                  v = c(-2, -3, -1, 1, 2, 1, -2, 2, 4, 3))
plot(dat, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "blue")
clip(x1 = min(dat$u),
     x2 = max(dat$u),
     y1 = min(dat$v),
     y2 = 0)
lines(dat, lwd = 2, col = "red")
abline(h = 0, col = "grey")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: If you know this question has been asked before and is a duplicate you should not answer it in that case and should vote to close it as duplicate.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for letting me know. I didn't know that. I can't see any `vote` option, so possibly I need more reputation for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am now using `clplot()` from the [plotrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) package:

```
dat <- data.frame(1:10, c(-2, -3, -1, 1, 2, 1, -2, 2, 4, 3))
library(plotrix)
clplot(dat[, 1], dat[, 2], levels = c(0), cols = c("red", "blue"), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [very flexible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18009173/6574038) from *@Kohske / @beroe* around, which can also be adapted on `lines`.

The method is that you estimate nullities.

```
dat.add <- do.call(rbind, 
                 sapply(1:(nrow(dat) - 1), function(i) {
                   f <- lm(x ~ y, dat[i:(i + 1), ])
                   if (f$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                   r <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(y=0))
                   if(dat[i, ]$x < r & r < dat[i + 1, ]$x)
                     return(data.frame(x=r, y=0))
                   else return(NULL)
                 })
)
```

Merge the nullites to your original data frame.

```
dat <- merge(dat, dat.add, all=TRUE)
```

Then do an empty plot and add segmented `lines`.

```
plot(dat, lwd = 2, type="n")
lines(dat[dat$y >= 0, ], col="blue")
lines(dat[dat$y <= 0, ], col="red")
abline(h = 0, col = "grey")
```

***Result***

[image]

Note, that the lines are not interrupted on the zero line, but `abline` at `0` hides this fact so we shouldn't care much in this case.

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(x = 1:10, y = c(-2, -3, -1, 1, 2, 1, -2, 2, 4, 
3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```